# Reaching a data returned by ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, dom-events

It writes the start and end dates that I prepared in the attachment to the screen with `console.log`; no problem, but how can I pass this with `this.setState`?

I want to transfer the dates written to the `console.log` screen to `this.setState`. how can I do that?

Date written to the console screen. I want to transfer with `setState`

on codesandbox

```
A this.setstat ({
       date: startViewDateComputed
})
```

So I want to transfer the data written to the console screen

or how do I get `startViewDateComputed` date from here?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-mcnulty-m6j64?file=/demo.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is your solution demo.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import { Plugin, Getter } from "@devexpress/dx-react-core";
import { ViewState } from "@devexpress/dx-react-scheduler";
import {
  Scheduler,
  WeekView,
  Appointments,
  Toolbar,
  ViewSwitcher,
  MonthView,
  DayView
} from "@devexpress/dx-react-scheduler-material-ui";

import { appointments } from "../../../demo-data/month-appointments";

const pluginDependencies = [
  { name: "DayView", optional: true },
  { name: "MonthView", optional: true },
  { name: "WeekView", optional: true },
  { name: "ViewState", optional: true }
];

// modified this component to accept startViewDateComputed and endViewDateComputed
const IntegratedDates = ({ startViewDateComputed, endViewDateComputed }) => {
  return (
    <Plugin dependencies={pluginDependencies} name="IntegratedDates">
      <Getter name="startViewDate" computed={startViewDateComputed} />
      <Getter name="endViewDate" computed={endViewDateComputed} />
    </Plugin>
  );
};
export default class Demo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate: null,
      endDate: null
    };
  }

  // added this 
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (
      nextState.startDate === this.state.startDate &&
      nextState.endDate === this.state.endDate
    ) {
      return false;
    }
    return nextProps === this.props && nextState === this.state;
  }

  //moved this inside class
  startViewDateComputed = ({ startViewDate }) => {
    this.setState(prev => ({ startDate: startViewDate }), ()=> console.log(this.state));
    console.log("start view date:", startViewDate);
    return startViewDate;
  };

  //moved this inside class
  endViewDateComputed = ({ endViewDate }) => {
    this.setState(prev => ({ endDate: endViewDate }), ()=> console.log(this.state));
    console.log("end view date:", endViewDate);
    return endViewDate;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Paper>
        <Scheduler data={appointments} height={660}>
          <ViewState
            defaultCurrentDate="2018-07-25"
            defaultCurrentViewName="work-week"
          />

          <WeekView startDayHour={10} endDayHour={19} />
          <WeekView
            name="work-week"
            displayName="Work Week"
            excludedDays={[0, 6]}
            startDayHour={9}
            endDayHour={19}
          />
          <MonthView />
          <DayView />

          {/* modified to pass props */}
          <IntegratedDates
            startViewDateComputed={this.startViewDateComputed}
            endViewDateComputed={this.endViewDateComputed}
          />

          <Toolbar />
          <ViewSwitcher />
          <Appointments />
        </Scheduler>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}
```

--- this should produce warning as trying to update state in the render method, in order to avoid that you can replace statements updating state by function call as below --

```
  onEndDateUpdated = (endDate) =>  {
    console.debug ('endDateReceived', endDate);
  }
  onStartDateUpdated = (startDate) => { 
    console.debug('startDate');
  }
  //moved this inside class
  startViewDateComputed = ({ startViewDate }) => {
    this.onStartDateUpdated(startViewDate);
    console.log("start view date:", startViewDate);
    return startViewDate;
  };

  //moved this inside class
  endViewDateComputed = ({ endViewDate }) => {
    this.onEndDateUpdated(endViewDate);
    console.log("end view date:", endViewDate);
    return endViewDate;
  };
```

Comment: my friend. Thank you for your help. But I get an error like the one below.

`

        index.js:1 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within 
           render). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
            in TemplateConnectorBase (created by AppointmentsBase)
            in TemplatePlaceholderBase (created by Context.Consumer)
            in Unknown (created by Context.Consumer)
            in Unknown (created by TimeTableAppointmentLayer)
,

Comment: added soln to fix warning,  basically if you try to update state it will again try to re render and may fall into never ending cycle of update and render, that's why I had to add shouldComponentUpdate, but if you replace calls to update state by method and do not update state it will go away, I have added parts needed to update below original solution.

Comment: your solution is very nice. but I get data via API with componentDidMount. But when shouldComponentUpdate is active, no data comes with the API